# Python tests to functions relying on a MySQL user and connetion

Tags: python, mysql, database-connection, pymysql, database-security

I am writing a `Python` test class with methods relying on a connection to a MySQL database. The purpose of the test class is to test another class used for simplifying interaction with the same database. The interaction is managed through `pymysql` which requires login credentials to a MySQL account.

I am investigating the possibility of automatically creating a MySQL test user on any server when executing the tests. My goal is to be able to install the code as a package and have the tests run with a setup procedure that returns the connection to a database without any involvement from the user.

I am currently only familiar with creating MySQL users through an already existing *superuser*. The temporary solution is to include a file with login credentials that is read and used by the test module.

I might be that I approach the problem from a completely wrong angle. In general I am trying to test code that executes MySQL commands and commits changes to a database. I am grateful of any tips, ideas or experiences.

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

Ideally your tests should not touch your DB at all. If you are testing your code - then tests should execute your code and check the correctness of the result. If DB is included in your testing process, then you are testing your code + DB.

For testing you should mock the PyMysql module itself, I agree with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28432652/4632951)