# How to create unit test in flask which uses flask_mysqldb?

Tags: mysql, flask, python-unittest

I am reading the tutorial [here](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-viii-followers)

But this tutorial uses sqlalchemy as following:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import unittest
from app import app, db
from app.models import User, Post

class UserModelCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite://'
        db.create_all()

    def tearDown(self):
        db.session.remove()
        db.drop_all()
```

in fact, I already wrote a web app that uses `from flask_mysqldb import MySQL`

the `__init__.py` in the tutorial looks like this:

```
from flask import Flask
from config import Config
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_migrate import Migrate

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(Config)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
migrate = Migrate(app, db)

from app import routes, models
```

I have `mysql=MySQL(app)` in my own `__init__.py`

can I replace `db` by `mysql` in the first part of the code to test my app?

and what about `app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite://'`?

I haven't use the sqlalchemy,just use flask_mysqldb

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Switching from SQLite to MySQL with Flask SQLAlchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27766794/switching-from-sqlite-to-mysql-with-flask-sqlalchemy)

Comment: But I haven't use the sqlalchemy

Comment: This article might be useful for you https://www.codementor.io/adityamalviya/python-flask-mysql-connection-rxblpje73.

Comment: If you want to write the unit test for database operations then you have to create a dummy database and tables separate from the main app to test your code.

Answer (score 0):

Sol:

use `testing.mysqld` module

[here](https://pypi.org/project/testing.mysqld/)

Reference:
[Mock a MySQL database in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28431452/mock-a-mysql-database-in-python)